# Angular-cli v.6 new project build failed?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I installed Angular CLI v.6. Then I create a new project.

```
npm install -g @angualr-cli@^6.0.0
ng new my-app
cd my-app
npm install
npm build
```

The build fails with the following error.

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 604 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 659 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 15.6 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,74): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,77): error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

Thanks.

---

Update:
The angular cli version:

```
ng version

Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
```

---

Update:
npm install -g @angular/cli@^6.0.0 deos not install the latest verison

npm install -g @angular/cli@"<7.0.0" will install the latest  version v.6. The problem sovled after install the latest Angular-cli v.6.2.9

Comment: Why not use the latest version of the CLI?

Comment: Check [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4540)

Comment: Thanks Richards. I expected that "^6.0.0" would install the latest v.6, but it didn’t. 
Now I use "npm install -g @angular/cli@"<7.0.0" ". The angular-cli is updated to v.6.2.9. The issue has gone. You save the day.

Answer (score 0):

Try rm -rf node_modules/ and npm install inside of my-app

Answer (score 0):

1.Uninstall the current angular cli. npm uninstall @angular/cli

2.Delete the folder : enter image description here.

[image]

3.Delete the temp file of node_module if any exist, using %AppData%\npm-cache in cmd.

4.Restart the system.

5.Give fresh install with npm install @angular/cli@ eg: 6.0.2

Done your are good to go. :)